# Mapbox GL JS: ignore map click event if marker is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I have a marker in the map. I want to change its state when it is clicked and change it back when other place on the map is clicked.

The problem is that `map.on("click", console.log)` is also fired upon clicking the marker.

I want to see only the marker clicked event, because map click invokes state rollback.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title></title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.39.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.39.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='map'></div>

<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'access token';

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
    center: [-65.017, -16.457],
    zoom: 5
});

var el = document.createElement('div');
el.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://placekitten.com/g/40/40/)';
el.style.width = 40 + 'px';
el.style.height = 40 + 'px';

new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
    .setLngLat([ -63.29223632812499, -18.28151823530889 ])
    .addTo(map);

el.addEventListener('click', console.log);
map.on('click', console.log);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think what you wanna do is to stop the event from getting handled twice when the user clicked on a marker. To do that you could just use `event.stopPropagation();`

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

In your code you can use it like this:

```js
 function handleKitten(e) {
   e.target.style.backgroundImage = 'url(http://placekitten.com/g/50/50)';
   e.stopPropagation();
 }

 function handleMapClick(e) {
   console.log('handleMapClick', e);
 }

 var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
   container: 'map',
   style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
   center: [-65.017, -16.457],
   zoom: 5
 });

 var el = document.createElement('div');
 el.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://placekitten.com/g/40/40/)';
 el.style.width = 40 + 'px';
 el.style.height = 40 + 'px';

 new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
   .setLngLat([ -63.29223632812499, -18.28151823530889 ])
   .addTo(map);

 el.addEventListener('click', handleKitten, false);
 map.on('click', handleMapClick);
```

I made a quick jsfiddle for demonstration:
https://jsfiddle.net/andi_lo/guzskv7n/7/

Answer (score -1):

You might wanna use `map.once()`, or `map.off()`, see: [Double on click event with mapbox gl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45663869/double-on-click-event-with-mapbox-gl)

Comment: I would probably use it in a different situation, for now, .stopPropagation() seems to be the optimal.