# Double on click event with mapbox gl

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am redrawing layers on style.load event and removing the layers

```
        map.on('style.load', function() {
           loadByBounds(tempBounds)              
        });

        function loadByBounds(b) {
          if (map.getLayer("cluster-count")) {
            map.removeLayer("cluster-count");
          }
          ...
          map.on('click', 'unclustered-point', function(e) {

            var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup()
              .setLngLat(e.features[0].geometry.coordinates)
              .setHTML(text)
              .addTo(map);
          })}
```

But how to remove  map.on('click') events? As when I click the point the Popup() displays 2 times. And when I change layer one more time the onclick event fires 3 times and so on. So I think I have to remove the click event but how? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might wanna use `map.once()`. This will add a listener that will be called only once to a specified event type. However after 1 click event got fired this event listener won't listen to any further click events.

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#evented#once

With `map.off()` it's basically the opposite of `map.on()` and you can use it to unregister any applied event listeners. However you would need to add event listeners without an anonymous function in order to use `map.off()`.

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#off

```js
// you would need to use a named function
  function clickHandler(e) {
    // handle click
  }

  map.on('click', clickHandler);
// then you can use 
  map.off('click', clickHandler);
  
// With an anonymous function you won't be able to use map.off
  map.on('click', (e) => {
    // handle click
  });
```

To prevent your app from registering multiple listeners you maybe need to set a flag that gets set after your first event listener got applied.

```js
let notListening = true;

function loadByBounds(b) {
  // ....
  if (notListening) {
    notListening = false;
    map.on('click', (e) => { 
      // do something 
    });
  }
}
```